# How to add bootstrap.css to pdf document itextsharp

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap, itext

took as a basis for this
http://dangtrung87.blogspot.com/2013/07/asp-generate-pdf-with-itextsharp.html
i have next code

```
  string htmlText = RenderViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "report", null, true);
       htmlText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(htmlText, @"\s+", " ");
       htmlText = htmlText.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r","").Trim();

        //Generate PDF
        using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 40))
        {

            htmlText = FormatImageLinks(htmlText);

            //define output control HTML
            var memStream = new MemoryStream();
            TextReader xmlString = new StringReader(htmlText);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memStream);

            //open doc
            document.Open();
            string arialuniTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");

          // Set factories
            var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

            // Set css
            ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

            IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
            cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/bootstrap.css"), true);

            cssResolver.AddCss(".shadow {background-color: #ebdddd; }", true);

            var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
            var xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);



            xmlParse.Parse(xmlString);
            xmlParse.Flush();

            document.Close();
            document.Dispose();



            return File(memStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "test.pdf");

        }
```

I have error here  xmlParse.Parse(xmlString);
Additional information: Input string was invalid.

if i change 
cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/bootstrap.css"), **false**); i have no error.

And i have pdf file but work only                 cssResolver.AddCss(".shadow {background-color: #ebdddd; }", true);

bootstrap style is not work (

how to correct add this ??

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have this error is because cssResolver must be initialized before being used in pipeline, try changing these lines

```
        // Set css
        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
        IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
        cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/bootstrap.css"), true);
        cssResolver.AddCss(".shadow {background-color: #ebdddd; }", true);
```

by

```
        // Set css
        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/bootstrap.css"), true);
        cssResolver.AddCss(".shadow {background-color: #ebdddd; }", true);
        IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
```

Try it, works fine for me.
Regards